# Python Flask Jinja Dynamic routing

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

On the html page

```
<a href=" {{ session['username']}}/{{ item.filename }}">{{ item.filename }}</a>
```

On the flask routing code :

```
@app.route("/<username>/<filename>")
def downloadimage(username, filename):
```

However, this isn't routing the routing method.
What's the issue here ?

Comment: What does the href link render as? You might be missing the preceding `/`. Also you can use the function `url_for` in Jinja templates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the url_for method here.
Use it like this:

```
<a href=" {{url_for('downloadimage', username=session['username'], filename=item.filename)}}">{{ item.filename }}</a>
```

Here, downloadimage is the name of the function added to the required URL, username and filename are the parameters that should be passed to the function.

Comment: Thanks. The link rendered as http://127.0.0.1:8080/downloadimage?username=a&filename=377425_1.jpg   
@app.route("/downloadimage")
def downloadimage(username, filename):
This raised a TypeError: downloadimage() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'username' and 'filename'

Comment: @app.route("/downloadimage")
def downloadimage():
    username = request.args.get('username')
    filename = request.args.get('filename')